# Using COM between different user accounts

Tags: c#, com

I need to do the following:

- Application "AppA" is run by user "UserA"
- Now AppA starts AppB using the runas-command (it is started as UserB)

Is it now possible to let AppA control AppB via COM? While everything works fine without the different user accounts, I can't seem to get the COM object in the case mentioned above.

By the way: I use Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject to get the COM object of AppB.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer so I don't know how relevant this is, hence the comment instead of an answer: In Win32, when creating an instance of a COM object, you can specify a user and password that will be used instead of your own credentials. If you already have user and password for the `runas`, you can use them for further communication, bypassing all security issues. But as I said, I don't know if this is possible in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the DCOM Security on the called COM Object. There is an [example here:](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesdawson/archive/2007/09/06/Configuring-DCOM-Security.aspx)

1. Given the ProgId
2. Find the DCOM Configuration in Component Services and get to the properties
3. Find the Security Tab and set the Launch and Activation Permissions, and give the caller the rights to do this.