# CreateProcessWithLogon and Marshal.GetActiveObject("PowerPoint.Application")

Tags: c#, winapi, com, ms-office, powerpoint

I have to attach to PowerPoint automation object run from other user. It needs to avoid conflicts with my automation object of PPT and user instance of one.

I created an internal windows user and use `CreateProcessWithLogon(...)` to start PowerPoint from its logon. Power Point is started normally and its owner is user that I want. But `Marshal.GetActiveObject("PowerPoint.Application")` returns the error `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE)`.

I could find the only mention about this method [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop/2005-06/msg00151.html), but there is no working sample.

Could anybody help me to give an access to PowerPoint automation object run from another user?

Comment: Please explain better what you mean by this: "It needs to avoid conflicts with my automation object of PPT and user instance of one."

Comment: @Chris: PPT uses the single instance of the application for automation and user objects. So any action with automation object is reflected on the user presentation. But it's not the point - when the application is finished unexpectedly - PPT automation object instance remains in memory and locks files which must be removed. I could kill this PPT process but users can work with it and it would be, say, not good. I don't speak about cases when user instance run as administrator and automation object with a normal privileges and otherwise. In this case the second instance cannot work at all.

Comment: I suspect default security settings don't allow you to access COM objects of other users. Did you check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7021528/1059776?